# Dynamically load content through anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JS Fiddle of what I want to do and it's almost there. https://jsfiddle.net/Fm6bR/1/

But what I want to do is have the content load when the URL is clicked from an email for example.

e.g. www.mocksite.co.uk/#A will load the content in A 
     www.mocksite.co.uk/#B will load the content in B etc.

When I run this on my test site I can see that the anchor tag is selecting the option just not displaying any of the content below it.

```
<span class="link"><a href="#A">A</a></span>
<span class="link"><a href="#B">B</a></span> 
<span class="link"><a href="#C">C</a></span> 
<div class="test-listing-container">
<ul class="test-full-list">
  <ul class="test-category-list">
    <a name="A"></a>
    <div class="anchor-header">- A -</div>
       <li id="test-list-A">
       <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1 - A</a>
       <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1 - A</a>
       </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="test-category-list">
    <a name="B"></a>
    <div class="anchor-header">- B -</div>
       <li id="test-list-B">
       <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1 - B</a>
       <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1 - B</a>
       </li>
  </ul>
     <ul class="test-category-list">
    <a name="C"></a>
    <div class="anchor-header">- C -</div>
       <li id="test-list-C">
       <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1 - C</a>
       <a href="some link" class="main" title="some title">Some Link 1 - C</a>
       </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
   $.noConflict();

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('ul.test-category-list').hide();

     jQuery(document).on('click', '.link a', function (evt) {
       var $a = jQuery(evt.currentTarget),
           name = $a.attr('href').substr(1),
           $a2 = jQuery('.test-listing-container').find('a[name="' + name + '"]'),
           $ul = $a2.parents('ul.test-category-list').first();

       jQuery('ul.test-category-list').hide(); // hide all 
       $ul.show(); // show the relevant one
     });
   });
</script>
```

The above is what I have done so far in the JS fiddle.

Ideally I won't have the 3 links anywhere in the HTML they will all be hidden and just be able to access the content as they have clicked through to the page.

I'm pretty new to javascript so if someone could show me it in a js fiddle and explain a little what they've done then that would be great

thanks in advance

Comment: what's the returned data?

Comment: Nothing, I can see it has been selected by the CSS changing the colour of the link but it will only load the content in the <li id="test-list-?"> if it has been clicked on

Comment: I mean what's the type of the data that the url returns?

Comment: can't you just load it in an iframe?